# which component of SQL Server architecture handles the user login requests?

Tags: sql-server

I was asked this question recently and I didn't find the answer or any detailed explanation on internet regarding this.Can anyone please explain or provide any reference link that explains about the component of SQL Server architecture that handles the user login requests?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: maybe this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/overview-of-sql-server-security